# I try to do lazy mode in my angular website

Tags: angular, lazy-loading

I try to do lazy mode in my angular website and this look some bugs for no reason i did as angular website showing `https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules`

Why my app don't work anymore? I doesn't know what to do anymore
that my files please wait for your help.

product.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from '../../home/home.component';
import { InfoComponent } from '../../info/info.component';
import { ProductRoutingModule } from './module.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent, InfoComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ProductRoutingModule,
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ProductModule { }
```

module.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from '../../home/home.component';
import { InfoComponent } from '../../info/info.component';


const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
    { path: 'info', component: InfoComponent }
];


@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ProductRoutingModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { guards } from '../../store/guards';
import { HomeComponent } from '../../home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [

  { path: '', component: HomeComponent, canActivate: guards },
  { path: 'product', loadChildren: () => import('./product.module').then(m => m.ProductModule) },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: 'product/home', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I am try to access `'product/info'`

app.module.ts

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './shared/modules/app-routing.module';

  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,


The bug is
```

core.js:6014 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type HomeComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and ProductModule! Please consider moving HomeComponent to a higher module that imports AppModule and ProductModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes HomeComponent then import that NgModule in AppModule and ProductModule.
Error: Type HomeComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule and ProductModule! Please consider moving HomeComponent to a higher module that imports AppModule and ProductModule. You can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes HomeComponent then import that NgModule in AppModule and ProductModule.

```
Please help me I am try to do it two days
```

Answer (score 2):

Good day!

I can see two solutions:

1. Create module e.g. HomeModule which has HomeComponent in `declarations` and in `exports` sections:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [HomeComponent],
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [HomeComponent]
})
export class HomeModule {}
```

After that, you should import this module in both modules (e.g. into your AppModule and into your lazy loaded module).

2. Rework you ProductRoutingModule and do direct restriction to another HomeComponent (your index route) instead of duplication:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: 'home', redirectTo: '/' },
    { path: 'info', component: InfoComponent }
];


@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ProductRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Thx for help , on your first way i don't understand - HeaderComponent I don't have that component  , and the second way doesn't work for me

Comment: @xpopqww, sorry, I meant HomeComponen. I'll update the answer

Comment: i don't understand why I need 3 classes for one root , and "(e.g. into your AppModule and into your lazy loaded module)." where it exactly my head blowing up when I try think about this issue .